# FeathersJS with Socket.io listening to events is silent

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, feathersjs

I feel like I'm so close to getting this working, but I'm missing the last step. It looks like I'm following the documentation exactly, but can someone help me understand what I'm missing. Here is my @angular service:

```
declare var require: any

const feathers = require('feathers/client');
const socketio = require('feathers-socketio/client');
const io = require('socket.io-client');

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from './user.service';

@Injectable()
export class FeathersService {

  socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000/');
  app = feathers().configure(socketio(this.socket));
  status = this.app.service('realtime/user_status');

  constructor(
    public user: UserService,
  ) {
    this.status.on('updated', ({status}) => {
      console.log('your status was updated', status);
      this.user.me.status = status;
    });
  }

  updateStatus(status) {
    const id = this.user.me._id;
    this.status.update(id, {status});
  }
}
```

then here is my router code (sub route: /realtime)

```
const feathers = require('feathers');
const realtime = feathers();

const socketio = require('feathers-socketio');
realtime.configure(socketio({ wsEngine: 'uws' }, (io) => {
  io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    socket.emit('news', { text: 'A client connected!' });
  });

  // Registering Socket.io middleware
  io.use((socket, next) => {
      // Exposing a request property to services and hooks
      socket.feathers.referrer = socket.request.referrer;
      next();
    });
}));

const UserService = require('../controllers/user_service');
realtime.use('/user_status', new UserService());

module.exports = realtime;
```

and finally here is my service

```
const User = require('../models/user');

class UserService {
  update(id, userProps, params, next) {
    const userID = id;

    User.findByIdAndUpdate({ _id: userID }, userProps, { 'new': true })
      .then(user => {
        console.log('userProps', userProps);
        console.log('user >>>', user);
        return Promise.resolve(user);
      })
      .catch(next);
  }
}

module.exports = UserService;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not returning the Promise in your service method

```
const User = require('../models/user');

class UserService {
  update(id, userProps, params) {
    const userID = id;

    return User.findByIdAndUpdate({ _id: userID }, userProps, { 'new': true })
      .then(user => {
        console.log('userProps', userProps);
        console.log('user >>>', user);
        return user;
      });
  }
}

module.exports = UserService;
```

Should do it.

Comment: thank you!!! I actually just figured this out haha, spent all morning working on it. installed a linter and wrote some tests also so it wasn't a waste of time. but this is awesome now that it works